# Why Flutter Build Apk and Flutter install on Release not working

Tags: android, flutter

I'm ready to release my Flutter app but following the steps as advised but after building Apk and running flutter install to transfer on device, the app barely opens and closely immediately. HOWEVER, if I then run Flutter run --release I am able to run the code on the mobile afterwards even doing another Flutter Install is ok. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this was to do with the different Architecture of the Mobile device the Application is to be tested e.g arm or arm64. Therefore depending on the device, one needs to run specific release for each device set i.e. use flutter run release with --target-platform options with either android-arm, android-arm64, android-x86, android-x64 options to release different apks for the respective device set